# Template Ribbon Bar in Word 2010 and 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon, word-2013

Two years ago, a client, using Word 2010, asked me to create a template with an extra tab  for the Ribbon Bar containing some special buttons linked to the template's VBA.

They are now moving over to Word 2013 and want me to update their template to 2013 (i.e. removing the Compatibility Mode as well as adding a couple of extra buttons to their specialized tab. At this stage I have only updated their template to 2013 and not added any more buttons to their Ribbon tab. I have also put their updated template in the correct folder where all the templates are kept in my system.

I asked them to send me a document created in their 2010 version of the template, opened it in my 2013 version and found that TWO specialized tabs are added to the Ribbon Bar: one from their 2010 version and the other one from the 2013 version.

Can anyone advise me, please, whether they are stuck with two specialized tabs whenever they open documents created earlier in Word 2010 or is there something I can do in the 2013 version to prevent this?

By the way, I use the Office Custom UI Editor for the XML work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what XML markup you use for Word 2010 and 2013 templates. Are they different? Why do you need to have different custom UI?

You can read about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Eugene for your comment. I will check this out. I would make the assumption that different XML markups would cause two different tabs to appear?

Comment: Yes, most probably you have got two different tabs defined.

Comment: I've checked both templates and both have the same XML schema markup: <customUI 
 onLoad="Ribbon_OnLoad"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">

Comment: Did you have a chance to compare the content?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that the XML is exactly the same in both templates. There is something I'm missing and I can't spot it. I don't know where to look next!